# C++ program behaviour depending on source code file set

Tags: c++, compilation

I want to create a program which behaves differently depending on a facultative additional source code file to compilation (where some people might add some differing functionality). I thought about function overloading, similar to the (non-compilable) following code:

file1.cpp:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <string.h>
 using namespace std;

 class base {
  public:
   void ausgeb() { cout<<"here output base"<<endl; }
 };

 class derive: public base;

 int main(int argc, char** argv)
 {
  derive beisp;
  beisp.ausgeb();
 }
```

file2.cpp:

```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <string.h>
  using namespace std;
  class base;
  class derive : public base
  {
   public:
   void ausgeb() { cout<<"here output derive"<<endl; }
  };
```

Now I wished that:

```
g++ -o o1 file1.cpp file2.cpp
```

and

```
g++ -o o2 file1.cpp
```

should produce executable files with differing output.
Might there be a possibilty to meet that need?

Comment: In `file2.cpp`, you can have an object at file scope whose constructor switches out the implementation of `derive` using the [pimpl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer#C.2B.2B) idiom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution is gcc specific, if you switch compiler, it most probably won't work any more...

file1.cpp:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

void printOut() __attribute__((weak));
void printOut()
{
    ::std::cout << "weak" << ::std::endl;
}

int main(int, char*[])
{
    printOut();
    return 0;
}
```

file2.cpp:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

void printOut()
{
    ::std::cout << "strong" << ::std::endl;
}
```

More advanced (left out printOut implementations):

file1.h:

```cpp
class Base
{
    virtual void printOut();
}
```

file1.cpp

```cpp
#include "file1.h"
Base& getInstance() __attribute__((weak));
Base& getInstance()
{
    static Base theInstance;
    return theInstance;
}

int main(int, char*[])
{
    Base& instance = getInstance();
    instance.printOut();
}
```

file2.cpp:

```cpp
#include "file1.h"
class Derived : public Base
{
    virtual void printOut();
}

Base& getInstance()
{
    static Derived theInstance;
    return theInstance;
}
```

More general solution, via defining a preprocessor symbol:

file1.h:

```cpp
class Base
{
    virtual void printOut();
}
```

file1.cpp

```cpp
#include "file1.h"
#ifdef USE_DERIVED
#include "file2.h"
#endif

void Base::printOut()
{
}

int main(int, char*[])
{
#ifdef USE_DERIVED
    Derived instance;
#else
    Base instance;
#endif
    instance.printOut();
}
```

file2.h:

```cpp
#include "file1.h"
class Derived : public Base
{
    virtual void printOut();
}
```

file2.cpp:

```cpp
void Derived::printOut()
{
}
```

and compile with

```
g++ file1.cpp
```

in one case and

```
g++ -DUSE_DERIVED file1.cpp file2.cpp
```

in the other one.